# When sequelize.import model, the tablename appear to have a extra 's' at the end

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, actionhero

I use `actionhero` + `sequelize` plus mysql. When I do this

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize("MJN", "testUser", "testPasss", {
            "host": "192.168.123.321",
            "dialect": "mysql",
            "port": 3306,
            "pool": {
                "maxConnections": 20,
                "maxIdleTime": 30000
            }
});

var MJNCustomer = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/../models/MJNCustomer.js");
```

I do `console.log(MJNCustomer.tableName);`, and it return `MJNCustomers` instead of `MJNCustomer`.

Here is `models/MJNCustomer.js`

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('MJNCustomer', {
    customerId:         DataTypes.STRING,
    fname:              DataTypes.STRING,
    lname:              DataTypes.STRING,
    address1:           DataTypes.STRING,
    address2:           DataTypes.STRING,
    city:               DataTypes.STRING,
    phoneNumber:        DataTypes.STRING
});
```

}

what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Add freezeTableName: true to your options

Comment: Yep, this is a sequelize setting (it tries to pluralize table names).  Freeze it like @JanAagaardMeier suggests!

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [ah-sequelize-plugin](https://github.com/evantahler/ah-sequelize-plugin) and then just access your models using `api.models` object.

> Models are loaded into api.models, so the example above would be
>   api.models.Project. These module.exports allow for a third optional
>   parameter "api" which is the ActionHero API object. This can be used
>   to access configs and initializer functions, among other things.